# when to use these variations of "static" in java

Tags: java

Can someone please explain the difference between the following cases and where would we use each one?
Thanks all

```
class A{
  static public void methodA()
}

static class B{
  static public void methodB()
}

static class C{
  public void methodC()
}
```

Edit:
Hello all thank for the answers. I maybe I was not clear enough. I am aware that classes B and C can not be declared static unless they are inner classes. I so in your answers please assume that they are inner classes. I want to know when would I declare them static and even when to declare their methods static. I know that a static method in a non static class means that you can call it from anywhere and it is generally to perform general operations that are not specific to an object. But why would you declare static class? 
I will check your answers again after you reread my edit and accept the most explanatory answer

Comment: Just to be sure: You're not mixing up C# with Java, are you?

Comment: Yes java I don't even know c#

Comment: What is the driving force behind this question? It seems kind of "out there". I reserve static methods for  utility methods -- methods that are "stateless" and methods that manipulate static variables only. I use static inner classes rarely, mainly implied static inner classes if I'm creating an inner enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *static* modifier is used to declare *static fields or class variables*.

> They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every
>   instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed
>   location in memory. Any object can change the value of a class
>   variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating
>   an instance of the class.

Source: ["Understanding Instance and Class Members"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Also note that Java supports both static variables and methods. So going by this, your first class would compile correctly, while the other two would fail.

Just to give an example:

```
class A{
    public static int STATIC_VALUE = 1; // is a valid static variable

    public static void method1(){ 
        //is a valid static method
    }

    /**
    * Is a valid static inner class
    */
    static class innerClassB{

    }
}
```

---

> But why would you declare static class?

There're some reasons as to why one might want to do that. For example, from this [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer
>   class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. **In
>   effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that
>   has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.**

A good example of this is the `static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>` used in places like the *HashMap* class.

The existence of the Entry class is closely related to the functioning of how HashMap stores/retrieves key/value pair stored as its content. As you can see the Entry class provides functionality only to the HashMap implementation, even though its *behaviorally equivalent* to a top-level class. So it does make sense to package it as part of the HashMap definition itself.

You can find similar usage with `private static class Entry<E>` in the LinkedList implementation.

Another reason that I can think of is a way for *white-box testing*. Since an inner static class has access to the private and protected static variables/methods of the outer class, you can very well use this to test the internal states of the outer class. *Some might consider this dirty but then it can sometimes be useful*

In my opinion, Static inner classes are mostly for convenience, and are generally based on your design principles.

Comment: @Snake: Updated my answer to provide some more details. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Class A would have a static class-level method.  It wouldn't be related to any of the class instances, it would

Class B and C are illegal, you can't define a class to be static.

Edit: like HFoE said, B or C would work if they're inner classes.  In that case, they would not be able to access instance attributes of the outer class.

Comment: `"you can't define a class to be static"`... unless they're inner classes!

Comment: Yeah that's true.  I assumed Snake was talking about outer classes.

Comment: I really have no idea what Snake is asking to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, after I answered it I was like... dude, wait, what?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two uses of `static` here.

- `static` on a class can only be used on nested classes; i.e. named classes declared inside other classes.  It means that instances of the nested class doesn't have a parent instance of the enclosing outer class.
- `static` on a method means that the method does not apply to an instance of the containing class; i.e. the body of the method cannot refer to `this`.

---

This means that your declarations of `B` and `C` are invalid as written, because they are not declared in an outer class.

(Another answer says that top level classes are implicitly static.  In a sense, that is true, but another way to look at it is that `static` is meaningless for top level classes.  Either way, the Java language simply does not allow you to declare a top level class as `static`.  It is a compilation error.)

Answer (score 0):

All outer level classes are static, but you can not mention the *static* reserved word for them, so B and C are illegal as outer level classes.

But all of the cases are valid inner classes. In this case, A is a member inner class, but B and C are static inner classes (equivalent to normal classes).

A and B contain an static method, but C does not.